# Confusion about the initial condition for Laplace transform

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework, laplace-transform

I was trying to solve this question with Laplace transform, but I am confused in this question. My confusion is that whether we have to include the initial condition of the capacitor or not. Because when I am considering the capacitor with its initial condition I am getting different answer and when I am not considering it I am getting something else.

Method 1: without capacitor's initial condition
$$\frac{V(s)}{20}+\frac{2}{s}+\frac{V(s)}{10s}=0$$

Method 2: With all initial conditions
$$2=\frac{V(t)}{R}+\frac{CdV(t)}{dt}+I_o+\frac{1}{L}\int V(t)dt$$
Substituting values and taking Laplace yields complex exponentials for V(t).

[image]

So my question is which one is correct?

Comment: From the schematic it looks like the switch is closed and there is 2A already flowing through the circuit. This would correspond to the t < 0 (before the event). Then the even happens t > 0 the switch is opened and your circuit changes state for which you have to find the solution with the 2A current as an initial condition ...

Comment: In steady-state with the 2 A source in the circuit, what is the voltage across the inductor?  Answering that will help you find the initial voltage across the capacitor.

Comment: @Preet. As per previous comment you need to consider all initial conditions. That may include current and voltages etc.